# How to get julia reinforcement library consistency?

Tags: julia, reinforcement-learning

Trying to run the code from

https://juliareinforcementlearning.org/docs/How_to_write_a_customized_environment/

comes to the following error in my environment:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching StateTransformedEnv(::Type{LotteryEnv},        ::typeof(identity), ::typeof(identity))
Closest candidates are:
  StateTransformedEnv(::E, ::P, ::M) where {P, M, E<:AbstractEnv} at ~/.julia/packages/ReinforcementLearningEnvironments/Pzsys/src/environments/wrappers/StateTransformedEnv.jl:4
  StateTransformedEnv(::Any; state_mapping, state_space_mapping) at ~/.julia/packages/ReinforcementLearningEnvironments/Pzsys/src/environments/wrappers/StateTransformedEnv.jl:15
```

(A) My question is (of course): how to solve this?

And (B) maybe (if you will: in addition to A):
I already asked another question concerning definitions of
reinforcment experiments with some problems in loading libraries for experiments
([How to start julia reinforcement experiments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74680232/how-to-start-julia-reinforcement-experiments))
and I had some other problems with using flux and other libraries in combinations
(e.g. also with this interestiong library:
https://github.com/JuliaReinforcementLearning/ReinforcementLearningAnIntroduction.jl)

Some of them can be used with adding some additional using-statements.
But one step further: Is there some way to define using-statements or an environment so consistent or general, that errors like this could be prevented, before they occur?
Or: how could I figure out more easily, which library/libraries (or
which versions of them) have to be added or combinated, if problems like this occur?

Thank you for any help with A (and B)!

Here is the code:

```
using ReinforcementLearning

Base.@kwdef mutable struct LotteryEnv <: AbstractEnv
           reward::Union{Nothing, Int} = nothing
end

RLBase.action_space(env::LotteryEnv) = (:PowerRich, :MegaHaul, nothing)

RLBase.reward(env::LotteryEnv) = env.reward

RLBase.state(env::LotteryEnv) = !isnothing(env.reward)

RLBase.state_space(env::LotteryEnv) = [false, true]

RLBase.is_terminated(env::LotteryEnv) = !isnothing(env.reward)

RLBase.reset!(env::LotteryEnv) = env.reward = nothing


 function (x::LotteryEnv)(action)
           if action == :PowerRich
               x.reward = rand() < 0.01 ? 100_000_000 : -10
           elseif action == :MegaHaul
               x.reward = rand() < 0.05 ? 1_000_000 : -10
           elseif isnothing(action) x.reward = 0
           else
               @error "unknown action of $action"
           end
       end


env = LotteryEnv()

#RLBase.test_runnable!(env)

n_episode = 1000


#for _ in 1:n_episode
#    reset!(env)
#    while !is_terminated(env)
#        env |> action_space |> rand |> env
#    end
#end


run(RandomPolicy(action_space(env)), env, StopAfterEpisode(n_episode))

hook = TotalRewardPerEpisode()

#run(RandomPolicy(action_space(env)), env, StopAfterEpisode(n_episode), hook)

#using Plots

#plot(hook.rewards)


using Flux: InvDecay

p = QBasedPolicy(
           learner = MonteCarloLearner(;
               approximator=TabularQApproximator(
                   ;n_state = length(state_space(env)),
                   n_action = length(action_space(env)),
                   opt = InvDecay(1.0)
               )
           ),
           explorer = EpsilonGreedyExplorer(0.1)
       )
       

wrapped_env = ActionTransformedEnv(
           StateTransformedEnv(
               env;
               state_mapping=s -> s ? 1 : 2,
               state_space_mapping = _ -> Base.OneTo(2)
           );
           action_mapping = i -> action_space(env)[i],
           action_space_mapping = _ -> Base.OneTo(3),
       )

LotteryEnv |> StateTransformedEnv |> ActionTransformedEnv

      
#typename(QBasedPolicy)
```

Comment: I think it would be better to ask this as two separate questions. The first question needs some more details, because it looks like your definition of `LotteryEnv` [does not include `<:AbstractEnv` in the `struct` definition](https://juliareinforcementlearning.org/docs/How_to_write_a_customized_environment/#An-Example:-The-LotteryEnv), but without a complete [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of _your_ code, it's hard to tell. The second question seems to be about Julia's concept of [project environments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/#Environments).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just added the complete code.